# Dual of the map $f: A \rightarrow eAe$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over a field $k$ and $e$ be an idempotent in $A$. Consider the $k$-linear map $f : A \rightarrow eAe$ such that $f(a)=eae$ for $a \in A$. If we take the $k$-dual of $f$, we obtain that $f^* : (eAe)^* \rightarrow A^*$ such that $f^* ((eae)^*)= (eae)^* \circ f$. I need to simplify the last equality. So can we simply say that $f^* ((eae)^*)= (eae)^*$?

Comment: It is not clear what $(eae)^*$ is supposed to be.  So no, we can't simply say that.

Comment: (eae)^* is just dual basis such that $(eae)^* (eae)=1$.

Comment: In order for $f^*((eae)^*)$ to be defined, $(eae)^*$ would need to be a map. Saying "$(eae)^*$ is just dual basis" does not define a map.

Comment: The problem is that there is no canonical identification between a vector space and its dual, so the expression $(eae)^*$ has no clear meaning unless you add more structure.

Answer (score 1):

Note that an element of $(eAe)^*$ is a $k$-linear map $g:eAe \to k$.  By definition, the dual of $f$ is defined so that $f^*(g):A \to k$ is the map defined by
$$
[f^*(g)](a) = [g \circ f](a) = g(eae).
$$

Comment: Yes I know it. But I need to simplify the part $g\circ f$. Also since $g \in A^*$ , can not we say $f^*(g) = g$?

Comment: @sm.s We cannot since $g \in (eAe)^*$.  $g$ is a map on $eAe$, but the output $f^*(g)$ is supposed to be a map on all of $A$.

Comment: @sm.s You could perhaps say that there are certain elements $g \in A^*$ such that $f^*(g|_{eAe}) = g$, though.  Specifying which maps $g$ have this property would completely define $f^*$.

Comment: I think the last comment was the thing that I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Good luck